# Truncated expectation equality

Tags: probability, expectation

can somebody please explain me how following equality works:

$E [|X|^pI(|X| \leq x) ] = \int_0^x y^pdP(|X| \leq x) = x^pP(|X| > x) + p\int_0^x y^{p-1}P(|X| > y) dy$.

First one should be just the definition of the expectation but i can't get the second one. I thought about partial integration but failed doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity doesn't look quite right. If $Y$ is a nonnegative RV with cumulative distribution function $F(y):=P(Y\le y)$ and tail probability function $R(y):=P(Y>y)=1-F(y)$, then
$$
E[Y^pI(Y\le x)]=\int y^pI_{(0,x]}(y)dF(y)=\int_0^x y^pdF(y)
=-\int_0^xy^pdR(y)\tag1$$
and using integration by parts the RHS of (1) equals
$$
\left.-y^pR(y)\right\vert_0^x +\int_0^xR(y)py^{p-1}dy=-x^pP(Y>x)+\int_0^xpy^{p-1}P(Y> y)dy,\tag2
$$
but this isn't what your identity is saying. Expressed in terms of $F$ we can similarly obtain
$$
E[Y^pI(Y\le x)]=x^pF(x)-\int_0^xF(y)py^{p-1}dy=x^pP(Y\le x)-\int_0^xpy^{p-1}P(Y\le y)dy,\tag3
$$
which also doesn't agree with your formula.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I found a mistake in my original identity on the RHS and edited it, so now it looks more similar to your (2) but it is still not exactly the same as you already mentioned.
I will think about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically integration by parts for Riemann Stieltjes integrals. See here for example: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/labute/courses/255w03/L3.pdf

So literarily, $\int_0^x udv =uv|_{0}^x-\int_0^x vdu$. If the CDF $P(|X|\leq x)$ is differentiable, then this is back to the usual Riemann integration by parts.